# Add validation on views bulk operations form

Tags: views

I have a content type on which I added a custom validation that there can't be more than 7 items of that content type that is marked as 'sticky'.  That validation was added on the add and edit pages through `omhm_mod_form_blog_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)` with the line `$form['#validate'][] = 'omhm_mod_form_nouvelle_node_form_validate';` and my custom validation `omhm_mod_form_nouvelle_node_form_validate`.

Now I have to make a page with views bulk operations with the same custom validation in place ... how can I do that ?

I'm trying to add the custom vbo validation `views_bulk_operations_form_validate($form, &$form_state)` to my `omhm_mod_views_bulk_operations_form_alter($form, &$form_state, $form_id)` hook with the line `$form['select']['submit']['#validate'][] = 'omhm_mod_carrousel_views_bulk_operations_form_validate';` but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `omhm_mod_views_bulk_operations_form_alter($form, &$form_state, $form_id)` takes `$form` by value, not by reference, so any changes made to `$form` are scoped to the function only. That's why `$form['select']['submit']['#validate'][]` changes nothing. It should be `omhm_mod_views_bulk_operations_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)`

When you fix mistake I pointed above, and it will not help, be sure to test if your hook is run at all, and if it is, then test if your validator is. It'll be needed for your next question, if you will need to ask it.

Comment: Yep, you're totally right ... dumb mistake on my part.  I modified the default error messages in the custom validation function and the modified messages appear when I submit the vbo form.  Just have to add my other validations now ... Thanks !